# Tailwind classes not reflecting on heading elements

Tags: tailwind-css

I made a react functional component called `Heading`. This is the code:

```
function Heading({
  color = "white",
  tag = "h1",
  text,
  fontSize = "6xl",
  margin = "",
  fontWeight = "normal",
}: Props): Element<any> {
  const Tag = tag;
  return (
    <Tag
      className={`text-${color} text-${fontSize} ${margin} font-${fontWeight}`}
    ></Tag>
  );
}
```

I think it's pretty straightforward, it even renders the correct HTML: `<h1 class="text-black text-6xl mb-5 font-normal">Dashboard</h1>`

But it still doesn't reflect the changes. I understand that the heading tag styling gets reset because of [preflight](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/preflight), but doesn't it get overridden when I apply the utility classes?

This is my `tailwind.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        primary: "#497BFA",
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

Comment: [See this](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#class-detection-in-depth)

Comment: You cannot construct your classes like `text-${color}`, you need to use something like `{(color === 'red') ? 'text-red' : 'text-white'}`

Answer (score 1):

This is intentional and discussed in [the docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/preflight/#headings-are-unstyled).

If you want to add default styles for elements like that you can do so by [adding custom base styles:](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-base-styles/#using-css)

```
@tailwind base;
h1 {
  @apply text-2xl;
}
h2 {
  @apply text-xl;
}
h3 {
  @apply text-lg;
}
a {
   @apply text-blue-600 underline;
}
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```