# Text color not changing using NextJS with Tailwind CSS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

In my NextJS app I'm using an `<h1>` tag for the text and wrap it in a `<div>` but when I try to apply a color to the text, it doesn't work. I even added in my `global.css` but it throws an error.

```
    <div className="mt-2 flex justify-start items-center text-2xl font-bold text-gray-300">
        <Image 
            src={Logo}
            width={40}
            height={40}
        />
        <h1>some text here</h1>
    </div>
```

The code above does not throw an error, but it also doesn't apply the style to the text.

**styles/global.css**

```css
    @tailwind base;
    @tailwind components;
    @tailwind utilities;
    
    @layer base{
        body{
            @apply bg-[#06202A] text-gray-300; 
        }
    }
```

Applying styles in the base layer (above) throws the following error.

> .../styles/globals.css The `text-gray-300` class does not exist. If `text-gray-300` is a custom class, make sure it is defined within a `@layer` directive.

**tailwind.config.js**

```js
@type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
    module.exports = {
      mode: "jit",
      content: [
        "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
        "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
      ],
      theme: {
        colors: {
          'main-bg-color': '#02172F',
          'text-gray-color': '#fff'
        },
        extend: {},
      },
      plugins: [],
    }
```

**postcss.config.js**

```js
    module.exports = {
      plugins: {
        tailwindcss: {},
        autoprefixer: {},
      },
    }
```

Why is this not working?

Comment: Could you also include your `tailwind.config.js` and `postcss.config.js` files in your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tailwind classes not reflecting on heading elements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71505992/1264804)

Comment: @EdLucas i have included.

Comment: Declaring a color this way `'text-gray-color': '#fff'` will require you to use it like this `text-text-gray-color`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are replacing the default colors with your new additions. To add colors, but keep the defaults, you should place your new colors within the `extend` property.

```js
module.exports = {
  mode: "jit",
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        'main-bg-color': '#02172F',
        'text-gray-color': '#fff'
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Also, the `mode` setting is no longer needed in Tailwind 3.0+. If you're still using V2, I would recommend upgrading if possible. If you cannot upgrade for some reason, I would like to point out that the default color classes are different between Tailwind 2 and 3, and you will have to reference the correct version's docs for the proper color set.

- V2: https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/customizing-colors
- V3: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/customizing-colors

Answer (score 0):

I've read tailwindcss config in nextjs and i saw that the tailwind config file is different if you choose .src folder or not when npx create next app. This solved my problem: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/nextjs

```
 content: [
"./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
"./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
"./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",

// Or if using `src` directory:
"./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
```

],